# Replace all strings in a dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| Price |
| --- |
| $ C145 |
| + $22.34 |
| From USA |

Hi this is the df I have above I basically want to remove all the special characters ( $, + and spaces). I then want to move them so they look like the table below as integers so I can process into a CSV and analyze the prices of over 50 rows.

| Price | Shipping | Origin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | 22.34 | From USA |

I was thinking maybe I need to put it in a data frame then use a iloc to shift it over?

```
Apples=["$ 145", "+ 22.34", "From USA"]
df=pd.DataFrame({'Price': Apples})

new_df=pd.DataFrame({'Price':df['Price'].iloc[::2].values, 'Shipping':df2['Price'].iloc[1::2].values})
```

At this point it takes the price and shipping but it only shifts it into two columns i just need it to be done for 3. How can I make it go into the columns like in the new table above and also strip columns "Price" and "Shipping" with all of the strings maybe something like this but replicate it for columns Price and Shipping? Thank you for any help i'm just starting out in Pandas and python really!

```
new_df['Price']=new_df.Price.str.extract(r'(\d+[.\d]*)')
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We expect **one** question at a time. Make sure it is clear and direct; and [do not talk about yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721), or anything besides the problem at hand - we [don't need](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160) thanks, and we don't need to be told that you want an answer (or you wouldn't be asking).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the orientation from vertical to horizontal can be done with a transpose:

```
df = df.T
df.columns = ['price', 'shipping', 'origin']
```

Then you can treat each column to convert the strings to integer or float as needed:

```
import re  # regular expressions

# Replace anything not a digit ('\D') with an empty string, then convert to 
# int
df.price = df.price.apply(lambda x: int(re.sub(r'\D', '', x)))

# Replace anything not a digit or decimal ('[^0-9.]') with an empty string, 
# then convert to float
df.shipping = df.shipping.apply(
    lambda x: float(re.sub(r'[^0-9.]', '', x)))

# put it all in a single function:
def convert_df(df):
    df = df.T
    df.columns = ['price', 'shipping', 'origin']
    df.price = df.price.apply(lambda x: int(re.sub(r'\D', '', x)))
    df.shipping = df.shipping.apply(
        lambda x: float(re.sub(r'[^0-9.]', '', x)))
    return df
```

This will work even if your initial input has multiple columns like:

```
apples = ['$ C145', '+ $22.34', 'From USA']
corn = ['$ C197', '+ $18.46', 'From Canada']
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'apples': apples, 'corn': corn})

convert_df(df2)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I have about 105 rows in my df so right now it has 1 column and the data in every 3 rows needs to go into these columns. Row 1 data in column 1, Row 2 data in column 2, Row 3 data in column 3 and do this for the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

So your data looks like: `price, shipping, origin, price, shipping, origin, price...`?
In that case you can extract every 3rd row with syntax like:

```
df.iloc[list(range(start, df.index.max(), 3)), :].reset_index(drop=True)
```

..then just concatenate them, and apply the number extraction as above.

```
# starting with, e.g.:
apples = ["$ C145", "+ $22.34", "From USA"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': apples * 30})
df.head(6)
```

```
    data
0   $ C145
1   + $22.34
2   From USA
3   $ C145
4   + $22.34
5   From USA
...
```

```
df = pd.concat(
    [
        # Get every 3rd row and reindex
        df.iloc[list(range(start, df.index.max(), 3)), :]
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         for start in [0, 1, 2]
    ],
    axis=1)
df.columns = ['price', 'shipping', 'origin']
df.price = df.price.str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)
df.shipping = df.shipping.str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d*)').astype(float)
df.head()
```

```
    price   shipping    origin
0   145     22.34       From USA
1   145     22.34       From USA
2   145     22.34       From USA
3   145     22.34       From USA
4   145     22.34       From USA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(df['Price'].str.replace(r'^\W', '', regex=True)
 .to_frame().assign(id = np.repeat(np.arange(len(df) // 3), 3), 
                    name = ['Price', 'shipping', 'origin'] * (len(df) // 3))
 .pivot(index='id', columns='name', values = 'Price')
 .reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  Price    origin shipping
0   145  From USA    22.34
1   123   From UK    12.45
```

Input:

```
      Price
0     $ 145
1   + 22.34
2  From USA
3     £ 123
4   + 12.45
5   From UK
```